# How to filter the json data using Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am new to Underscore. I have a json array which is pasted below. If I want to filter the below array based on `developed` field having "yes" as value. How can I do using Underscore.js. Currently I am iterating over the content of array and manually selecting the objects and populating in into another array. Is there a better way to do using Underscore?

```
  {
    "content": [
    {
      "stateName": "Karnataka",
      "population": 1000000,
      "developed": "yes"
    },
    {
      "stateName": "Kerala",
      "population": 1000000,
      "developed": "yes"
    },
    {
      "stateName": "Tamilnadu",
      "population": 1023213213213,
      "developd": "yes"
    },
    {
      "stateName": "Bsadasd",
      "population": 1023213213213,
      "developed": "no"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm missing something here but the obvious underscore function is [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var developedStates = _.filter(data.content, function(state){
    return state.developed == 'yes';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter an array on its properties by using [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) :

> **where** _.where(list, properties)
>
> Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the
>   key-value pairs listed in properties.

which leads to

```
var filtered = _.where(data.content, {developed: "yes"});
```

and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/NExZC/

Comment: I looked through so many SO questions looking for a simple answer like this.  I new there had to be a concise one-liner but everyone seems to be using the `return` approach for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, underscore doesn't have a way to help you with this task. You can do this without using underscore with a native Javascript method called [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filteredArray = originalArray.select(function(item, index) {
    return item.developed == "yes"; // Include this item if it has a proper value
});
```

Note that the `select` method is only available in browsers that support EcmaScript 5 specifications, so for older browsers you will need some supporting library like [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).